# Is there a way to load page in sequence with Jquery?

Tags: jquery, load, loading, sequence

I have a long scrolling page, so i want to load contents of the page in sequence.

```
<div id="one">one.php</div>
<div id="two">two.php</div>
<div id="three">three.php</div>
```

on page load, i want to load content of only DIV id ONE, after that DIV id TWO then DIV id THREE.. and so on..

How do i achieve that? I created 3 files (one.php, two.php, three.php) tried .load() but i am not able to make a sequence. Please help!

Comment: Isn't that the natural order? you can use AJAX to load them one by one in sequence if not

Comment: The best way is to use ajax for that. You can call them bit by bit, one after the other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). This method allows you to specify what will happen on success. So once you will load first div's contents, in success handler load second div's contents and so on. Something like this:

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>
<div id="div3"></div>

$.ajax({
    url: 'div1.html',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "html",
    success: function (response) {

        $("#div1").html(response);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'div2.html',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "html",
            success: function (response) {

                $("#div2").html(response);

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'div3.html',
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function (response) {
                        $("#div3").html(response);
                    }
                });

            }
        });

    }
});
```

But remember - it will not work with local files - you need to set up some web server, as at least `Chrome` doesn't want to load local resources via `ajax`. Of course there is a way to change `Chrome` options but I wouldn't play with it.

Comment: Can u please help me with a link which explains how to do that? any online tutorial.. I tried looking for it but couldnt really find, may be my keywords r wrong :(

Comment: Just have added some code. You can also look at the @Swarnajith solution - it's simpler if you don't need additional options.

Comment: Added HTML and full solution.

Comment: Learnt something new today, Thanks Carlos :)

Comment: Cool - this is what SO is for :)

Answer (score 4):

Try using, [jQuery.load();](http://api.jquery.com/load/),

```
$("#one").load("../content1.php", function() {
  $("#two").load("../content2.php", function() {
    // likewise
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this :

```
$('#one').load("one.php", function() {  // first div loaded
    $('#two').load("two.php", function() { // second div loaded
        $('#three').load("three.php", function() { // third div loaded  });
    });
});
```

Comment: I`ll definitely try, does jquery .load() function work everywhere? or does it have issues in old browsers? Is ajax a better option?

Comment: This will work everywhere. I believe this is a better option than ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you are using jQuery.load to load content to your divs, the .load function has a callback function parameter (that is, a function to call after the contents have completed loading). With this you can assure that you can load them in the order you need (see http://api.jquery.com/load/)

For example:

```
$("#one").load(url, function(response, status, xhr) {
     $("#two").load( ... etc )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

2 ways:

1) use a timer to load the page content every 2000 ms etc.
2) an event should be fired to tell JS that next part should be loaded [example is the feed in fb, once you scroll down it starts to load the latter part]

loading can be simply done by $('#one').load("one.html");

Answer (score 0):

**Option 1** 
Use setTimeout

```
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#one").show();
    }, 1000);
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#two").show();
    }, 2000);
setTimeout(function() {
        $("#three").show();
    }, 3000);
```

**Option 2** 
Function 2 Function Transition.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#one").show();
showTwo()
});

function showTwo()
{
$("#two").show();
showThree()
}

function showThree()
{
$("#Three").show();
}
```

**NOTE**: For both, you need to first hide them onload. To do this, use the below function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#one").hide();
$("#two").hide();
$("#three").hide();
    });
```